# Slider Not Transforming Article Element (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, events, transform

I have a simple slider where one of the articles is set partially off the screen and when I click the directional arrows I would like it to slide in.

The code is below, but when I click the 'left' button it doesn't slide in, yet I'm not getting any error messages?

[Click here for codepen](https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/RwGZGPv)

```js
var leftButton = document.getElementById("left-button"),
  rightButton = document.getElementById("right-button"),
  article = document.querySelectorAll(".article"),
  counter = 0,
  articleWidth = article.offsetWidth;

if (counter === 0) {
  leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    article.forEach(function (item) {
      item.style.transform = 'translateX("-100%")';
      counter += 1;
    });
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.article-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 130%;
}

.article {
  width: 70%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 4rem 1rem;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <article class="article">
      <p class="td">Article 1</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p class="td">Article 2</p>
    </article>
    <article class="article">
      <p class="td">Article 3</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="left-button">Left</button>
<button id="right-button">Right</button>
```

Comment: You need `translateX(-100%)`, without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your transform translate percentage wrapped in quotes, remove your quotes and it will work.

See the examples @ MDN: [MDN translateX()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX)

```js
if (counter === 0) {
  leftButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    article.forEach(function (item) {
      // do not wrap your percentage or value in quotes within the translateX property 
      item.style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
      counter += 1;
    });
  });
}
```